# Why the output of difftime does not start from zero for each group

Tags: r

I have a dataset including user_ids, datetime, and index (which shows the activity number for each user_id). I have to find the time difference for each activity. Therefore, this new column (walk_time) should start with NA for a unique activity and have the time difference values in all the rows for that index (activity). However, I use my code, but it does not consider the group_by(index). Here is my code and the output of my code.
p.s.: I used dput() in R based on the replies from my last post in Stack Overflow and copied and pasted my data here. Please let me know If I should bring my data in another way. 
I want to compute the difference between consecutive time data, but I have to group them.

```
sample_DF$walk_mins <- as.numeric("")
sample_DF <- sample_DF %>%
  group_by(index.y) %>%
  mutate(walk_mins = as.numeric(difftime(DATETIME2 , lag(DATETIME2) , units = "mins")))
```

user_id DATETIME2           index.y walk_mins
                            
 1      41 2019-06-02 20:44:00       1        NA
 2      41 2019-06-03 16:46:00       2      1202
 3      41 2019-06-03 16:50:00       2         4
 4      41 2019-06-03 20:43:00       3       233
 5      41 2019-06-03 20:44:00       3         1
 6      41 2019-06-03 21:00:00       4        16
 7      41 2019-06-04 13:28:00       5       988
 8      41 2019-06-04 13:29:00       5         1
 9      41 2019-06-04 13:30:00       5         1
10      41 2019-06-04 13:31:00       5         1
11      41 2019-06-04 13:32:00       5         1
12      41 2019-06-04 13:34:00       5         2
13      41 2019-06-04 13:35:00       5         1
14      41 2019-06-04 13:36:00       5         1
15      41 2019-06-04 17:31:00       6       235
16      41 2019-06-04 18:46:00       7        75
17      41 2019-06-04 19:13:00       8        27
18      41 2019-06-04 19:37:00       9        24
19      41 2019-06-04 19:55:00      10        18
20      41 2019-06-04 20:13:00      11        18

Comment: Can you please check my soltuion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the `difftime` to start from 0, change the `default` in 'lag' too `first` of 'DATETIME2'.  By default, it is `NA`.  Also, based on the output showed, it seems that the `plyr::mutate` masked the `dplyr::mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
sample_DF <- sample_DF %>%
       group_by(index.y) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(walk_mins = as.numeric(difftime(DATETIME2 ,
      lag(DATETIME2, default = first(DATETIME2)) , units = "mins")))
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun for answering. I ran your code. It does not add the "walk_mins" column.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I just ran the updated code. Now, it worked. I appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: @Sia thanks for testing.  WIth `dplyr`, it wouldn't update the original object with `%>%` unless you used `%<>%` from `magrittr`